# Strange CSS property behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, cursor

I've always been able to solve problems in css(even after a few days) but this time, I have no idea, and friends also.

Simply putted, the `:hover` property and `cursor` property target what should not be targetted.

Below, I've putted *FIDDLE* code and HTML+CSS+JS and under it is thorough problem description.

*FIDDLE* https://jsfiddle.net/Lkxragtb/

> HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Experiment - jQuery</title>
<link rel="icon" href="" type="image/gif">
<meta name="author" content="Michal Šeps">
<meta name="description=" content=""> 
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="java.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/main.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--Google Analytics-->
</script>
</head>

<body>

<nav id="nav_left">
    <ul>
        <li>Expermient JQ 01
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 01</li>
                <li>The Test 01</li>
                <li>The Test 01</li>
                <li>The Test 01</li>
                <li>The Test 01</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Expermient JQ 02
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 02</li>
                <li>The Test 02</li>
                <li>The Test 02</li>
                <li>The Test 02</li>
                <li>The Test 02</li>
                <li>The Test 02</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Expermient JQ 03
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 03</li>
                <li>The Test 03</li>
                <li>The Test 03</li>
                <li>The Test 03</li>
                <li>The Test 03</li>
                <li>The Test 03</li>
                <li>The Test 03</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Expermient JQ 04
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 04</li>
                <li>The Test 04</li>
                <li>The Test 04</li>
                <li>The Test 04</li>
                <li>The Test 04</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Expermient JQ 05
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 05</li>
                <li>The Test 05</li>
                <li>The Test 05</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Expermient JQ 06
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
                <li>The Test 06</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Expermient JQ 07
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 07</li>
                <li>The Test 07</li>
                <li>The Test 07</li>
                <li>The Test 07</li>
                <li>The Test 07</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Expermient JQ 08
            <ul class="nav_left_ul02">
                <li>The Test 08</li>
                <li>The Test 08</li>
                <li>The Test 08</li>
                <li>The Test 08</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*UPPER LEVELS*/




/* CSS Document */
/* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 - http://cssreset.com */
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}

/*V prďż˝pade ďż˝e nenďż˝ podporovďż˝n browserem, muďż˝e tohle pomoct*/
nav, aside, main, details, header, hgroup, menu, article, section, footer, figure, figcaption, small {
        display: block;
    }


/*LINKS, HEADER, NAVIGATION LEFT, MAIN, FOOTER, LINKS*/

body {
    background-color: rgba(129,70,0,1.00);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    }



/*---------------------------------------LINKS------------------------------------------*/

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    }




/*------------------------------------NAVIGATION LEFT---------------------------------------*/
#nav_left {
    width: 170px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    }

    #nav_left > ul {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    }

    #nav_left > ul > li {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    border: solid 2px rgba(255,255,255,1.00);   
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

    #nav_left > ul > li:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }



/*------navigation left second ul set------*/   
.nav_left_ul02 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 170px;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.30);
    }

    .nav_left_ul02 > li {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-weight:100;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    border: solid 2px rgba(255,255,255,1.00);   
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }   

    .nav_left_ul02 > li:hover {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }   

    .nav_left_ul02 > li > a {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    }
```

> JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {




$("#nav_left > ul > li").click(function(){
    if ( $(".nav_left_ul02").is(":visible") ) {
        $(".nav_left_ul02").hide();
        $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").show();
        console.log("1 fired");
    } else {
        $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").show();
        console.log("2 fired");
    }
 });



/*$("#nav_left > ul > li").click(function(){
        $("#nav_left > ul > li > ul").hide();
        $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").show();
   });*/


/*$("#nav_left > ul > li").click(function(){
        $(".nav_left_ul02").toggle();
   });*/


/*
$("#nav_left > ul > li").click(function(){
    if ( $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").is(":visible") ) {
        $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").hide();
    } else {
        $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").hide();
        $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").toggle();
    }
});
*/


/*$("#nav_left > ul > li").click(function(){
        $(this).children(".nav_left_ul02").toggle();
   });*/

});
```

> PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

As you will see, I used the    **>**     sign to target specific children. When you hover over the  second line in menu, It works as it should. Then you click on something and second line of inside-menu opens, as it should. But, now if you hover there, you will notice that Both the
first AND the second line of `<li>` children blinks!, That is not set
there!. AND if you notice, In the second  inside-menu, If you hover
only over the   `<ul>` box and not over the `<li>` box, The first line of menu still gets affected. There is nothing about hovering `<ul>` or making a `cursor:pointer` for   `<ul>`'s  at all. It gets even weirder, When you notice that this multi-connection doesn't work on all the properties. The fonts are separated if you change them, same is the case with background or border. But setting a `cursor` and `hover` in the first line of `<li>`   affects suddenly also the second line of `<li>`.
The whole problem is in css, maybe in html(not probable), but not in JavaScript(definitely not, although of course, I am still just a student)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! One of the main things to do before posting a question is to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve), so that your question can have a **small** example of the problem and people don't have to wade through reams of code. Also, please **don't put a bunch of things in boldface** as it makes the text harder to read, and don't mark up things as quotes that aren't quotes. To the good: Excellent that you included the code *in* the question, and having a fiddle is a great addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got nested elements:

```
ul > li > ul > li
```

So, when you are hovering the most nested `li` you are hovering all its parent at the same time.

You changing the position of the nesting `ul` but it remains in the DOM as nested element of your first level `li`. So, when you place your mouse cursor over the second level (or even third level `li`), you are hovering the first level `li` too.

**UPD**

You can add some CSS class (like `current`) by JavaScript to menu item on hover. And this class will set all the styles for hovered item.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've honestly thought about this but quickly dismissed that possibility cause I thought that complex navigation are just all done in this way, in the way of nesting each on of them in the whole group. So... it does not work that way?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pavlito/kthhkc88/)

I just add simple jquery block code.

```
$(".nav_left_ul02 li").on("mouseover", function (){
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background", "none");
});
```